# Are constants optimized by clang in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, constants

I previously was using preprocessor macros to define constants, and then found out they're a bad idea. They were in a header file named `Global.h`. So I created a `Global.m` file and ignored it from git with this content:

```
#if DEBUG

BOOL const GodMode = YES;
BOOL const TutorialDisabled = YES;

#elif STAGING

BOOL const GodMode = YES;
BOOL const TutorialDisabled = NO;

#else

BOOL const GodMode = NO;
BOOL const TutorialDisabled = NO;

#endif
```

and the `Global.h` having this content:

```
extern BOOL const GodMode;
extern BOOL const TutorialDisabled;
```

The `STAGING` macro is defined in the project setting's `Preprocessor Macros` for my custom `Configuration` named `Staging` as `STAGING=1`.
The `DEBUG` macro is the default one generated by Xcode similar to staging: `DEBUG=1`.

Sometimes, I want to write code that gets executed only for the `Debug` configuration, without the need to add a new constant.

So I started using:

```
#if DEBUG

// do something

#endif
```

that have these pros/cons:

- pros:

  - the `// do something` doesn't even exist for the other configurations, so the app size doesn't increase and there is no risk of a typo or something (e.g. adding a `!`) that will cause it to run when not needed
- cons:

  - the "unnecessary compiled files" problem is back; everytime I change the run configuration, the files that use this need to be compiled again, which increases the build time
  - weird syntax style; I don't know if I should increase the indentation of the `// do something` to match the `#if` or the code around it, or if I should add empty lines like above or not, or if they should be at the start of the line of at the same indentation level as the code; having something like:

```
if (Debug) {
    // do something
}
```

sounded like a better idea, so I changed `Global.h` to:

```
extern BOOL const Debug;
extern BOOL const Staging;
extern BOOL const Release;

extern BOOL const GodMode;
extern BOOL const TutorialDisabled;
```

and `Global.m` to:

```
#if DEBUG

BOOL const Debug = YES;
BOOL const Staging = NO;
BOOL const Release = NO;

BOOL const GodMode = YES;
BOOL const TutorialDisabled = YES;

#elif STAGING

BOOL const Debug = NO;
BOOL const Staging = YES;
BOOL const Release = NO;

BOOL const GodMode = YES;
BOOL const TutorialDisabled = NO;

#else

BOOL const Debug = NO;
BOOL const Staging = NO;
BOOL const Release = YES;

BOOL const GodMode = NO;
BOOL const TutorialDisabled = NO;

#endif
```

and it worked.

For some reason,

```
static BOOL const Debug = DEBUG;
static BOOL const Staging = STAGING;
static BOOL const Release = (!DEBUG && !STAGING);
```

threw the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'STAGING'`, even though it's defined exactly like `DEBUG`: meaning that there is no `DEBUG=0` for the other configurations:

```
//:configuration = Debug
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1

//:configuration = Staging
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = STAGING=1

//:configuration = Release
```

But, looking at the `Preprocess` Assistant editor view, the `if (Debug) {` shows up.

My question is, will the `if` check actually remain in the code for the, say, Release configuration? If yes, is there a better way to achieve what I described previously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No better way to tell than by trying this out ourselves. Taking your `Globals.h` and `Globals.m` file, I wrote the following `main.m`:

```
#import "Globals.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main()
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        if (Debug) {
            puts("We're in debug mode");
        } else if (Staging) {
            puts("We're in staging mode");
        } else {
            puts("We're in release mode");
        }
    }
}
```

Very simple, just prints out what mode we're in. Let's compile this and run it to see what happens:

```
$ clang -g -fobjc-arc -o var_test main.m Globals.m && ./var_test
We're in release mode
```

Looks reasonable — we didn't provide either `DEBUG` or `STAGING`, so we must be in release mode. (`-g` tells clang to output debug information, in case it's useful; `-fobjc-arc` turns on ARC; `-o` tells clang to output an executable with a specific name.) Just to test:

```
$ clang -g -DDEBUG -fobjc-arc -o var_test main.m Globals.m && ./var_test
We're in debug mode
$ clang -g -DSTAGING -fobjc-arc -o var_test main.m Globals.m && ./var_test
We're in staging mode
```

All good, looks like it works! (`-DDEBUG` defines `DEBUG` in the preprocessor; `-DSTAGING` does the same for `STAGING`.) Now the question is, does clang get rid of the if-statement and replace the code with just a print statement? I won't assume anything about your assembly skills, so let's take a look at what the compiler generated through [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com)'s pseudo-code mode (this loads in the object code generated by the compiler and reverse-disassembles it into something resembling C code):

```
int _main() {
    var_10 = objc_autoreleasePoolPush();
    if (*(int8_t *)_Debug != 0x0) {
            puts("We're in debug mode");
    }
    else {
            if (*(int8_t *)_Staging != 0x0) {
                    puts("We're in staging mode");
            }
            else {
                    puts("We're in release mode");
            }
    }
    objc_autoreleasePoolPop(var_10);
    rax = 0x0;
    return rax;
}
```

The variable names are gone and this looks a bit like some weird C/assembly hybrid, but it's pretty clear that the if-statement is still in there...

Well, okay, maybe if we try to optimize the build a little bit? Maybe Clang isn't making any optimizations here.

```
$ clang -g -O2 -fobjc-arc -o var_test main.m Globals.m
```

(`-O2` turns on somewhat aggressive compiler optimizations.) Hopper output:

```
int _main() {
    rbx = objc_autoreleasePoolPush();
    if (*(int8_t *)_Debug != 0x0) {
            rdi = "We're in debug mode";
    }
    else {
            if (*(int8_t *)_Staging != 0x0) {
                    rdi = "We're in staging mode";
            }
            else {
                    rdi = "We're in release mode";
            }
    }
    puts(rdi);
    objc_autoreleasePoolPop(rbx);
    return 0x0;
}
```

Okay, slightly different, but it's still in there! What gives?

For many compiled languages, C/Objective-C included, compilation happens in a few stages. Every .m file that you include in your project gets compiled into object code separately (the compilation phase), and then all the produced object code files get *linked* together (the link phase). The key here is that each .m file is compiled *separately* — even though the variables are defined statically in `Globals.m`, when `main.m` is compiled, the compiler has no idea about the values of `Debug` and `Staging` — all it saw is the *declarations* in `Globals.h` that say "hey, someone down the line will provide actual values for these variables, I promise"; it's up to the linker to glue these together. (This is why you can compile `main.m` into `main.o` just fine, even if you forget to define `Debug` and `Staging` — it's only when you try to *link* all of the .o files into an executable that you get a *linker* error telling you that there's a problem.)

Okay, so this is a linking issue, then, not a compilation issue. Is there any way we can get the linker to figure this stuff out for us? Yes, yes there is. :)

```
$ clang -g -flto -fobjc-arc -o var_test main.m Globals.m && ./var_test
We're in release mode
```

Hopper output:

```
int _main() {
    rbx = objc_autoreleasePoolPush();
    puts("We're in release mode");
    objc_autoreleasePoolPop(rbx);
    return 0x0;
}
```

Ah, much better! The `-flto` flag enables [Link Time Optimization](http://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html) that allows the linker to look through the .o files as it's gluing them together and optimize based on what it sees. Linking will take a bit longer with optimizations enabled (you can enable LTO in your target's Build Settings in Xcode), but will perform optimizations like this.

---

Now, for the real question: is this even a good way to do this? Eh, perhaps not.

Turning on LTO just for this is a bit overkill. There is no harm in using `#if DEBUG` in your code, and it's actually relatively common to see. You can keep the indentation exactly the same as it would be otherwise:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    if (/* some calculation setting x */) {
#if DEBUG
        NSLog("Calculation succeeded: %d", x);
#endif

        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you'd prefer to stick with the variable approach, you are welcome to define the variables as `static` variables in your `Globals.h`, eliminating `Globals.m` entirely (and getting rid of the need for LTO):

```
#if DEBUG
static BOOL const Debug = YES;
static BOOL const Staging = NO;
static BOOL const Release = NO;

static BOOL const GodMode = YES;
static BOOL const TutorialDisabled = YES;
#elif STAGING
static BOOL const Debug = NO;
static BOOL const Staging = YES;
static BOOL const Release = NO;

static BOOL const GodMode = YES;
static BOOL const TutorialDisabled = NO;
#else
static BOOL const Debug = NO;
static BOOL const Staging = NO;
static BOOL const Release = YES;

static BOOL const GodMode = NO;
static BOOL const TutorialDisabled = NO;
#endif
```

You can also use your

```
static BOOL const Debug = DEBUG;
static BOOL const Staging = STAGING;
static BOOL const Release = (!DEBUG && !STAGING);
```

version. The reason it's not working is exactly what you say yourself: "there is no DEBUG=0 for the other configurations". If you don't define `DEBUG`, what's the compiler supposed to do with `static BOOL const Debug = DEBUG;`? You should define `DEBUG=0` in staging and release modes, and `STAGING=0` in debug and release modes for this to work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't believe how awesome this answer is! Learned a lot from it. I forgot to say that the `Global.m` file has another purpose too: get rid of the need of commits that just toggles stuff like `GodMode`, that's why it's ignored in git.

Comment: Having the constants defined as `static` enables the unused `#if`s to be removed without activating LTO?

Comment: About the last part, I think the reason that `static BOOL const Debug = DEBUG;` worked was because I was building the project with the Debug configuration, silly me. So most probably running it in Staging would throw the same error for `Debug` too.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Glad to have helped. :) About your last comment, that is correct — you would get an error there just the same. About `Globals.m` not being tracked by git, though: are you the only one working on this project? Because if `Globals.m` is not tracked by git, anyone (including yourself) who clones your repo would get a linker error on compilation, because `Globals.m` would be missing, and nothing would define those variables...

Comment: I'm not the only one, but I know about that. I created a `sample.Global.m` file and a small script that copies it with the correct name :D

Comment: What about my second reply (question), but replacing `#if` with `if {` (can't edit it anymore)

Comment: @IulianOnofrei There are a few things at play here. The keyword `static` means "only available in this file", and for variable declarations it additionally means "this has global storage". My recommendation to make these vars `static` involves moving them from `Globals.m` into `Globals.h` — every file that imports `Globals.h` will get its own `Debug`, `Staging`, `Release` vars, and so on (but you get to set them globally). However, this is not much better than macros (which would require no optimization), but also, does not necessarily answer what you want to do with `GodMode`.

Comment: Here is what I would actually recommend, regarding all of this: make all of these vars macros, and you can eliminate the globals altogether. If you define all these macros to always either be `0`/`NO` or `1`/`YES`, you will be able to use them both in `#if` and `if (...) {...}`, and they will be completely transparent to the compiler (requiring no LTO). When you want god mode, simply compile with `GODMODE=YES`, and code that either does `#if GODMODE` or `if (GODMODE) { ... }` will get optimized correctly (`#if GODMODE` optimization is guaranteed because it's a preprocessor directive).

Comment: No need to have `Globals.h` or `Globals.m`, and if you want to enable the tutorial or god mode, just compile with that macro turned on. You can set either to `NO` or `YES` for every compilation cycle that you want. If you want to not share that setting with everyone else, my recommendation would be to just not commit the line if you change the config (this is easy to do with git). This is cleaner and easier than sharing a template file and having git ignore the real file, IMO.

Comment: That has another problem I avoided in the past, it greatly increases the compilation time if the `Global.h` file is imported in many files. And I kind of hate macros used like constants, as others do too. What I still didn't understand was the difference between `extern` and `static` regarding the `Debug`, `Staging` and `Release` constants.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei My recommendation is to compare the effects of LTO vs. `static`s in `Globals.h` on compilation time; LTO may be fast, or it may be slow. The fastest solution of all of these will be the macro approach, but if you don't like that, you still have options. :)